# Passing value from SelectableItemList in View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of strings in my Controller that is shown in a DropBox.

Controller

```
public ActionResult what()
{
    LeetCode lc = new LeetCode();
    lc.ProblemList = new[] 
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value="1", Text="Search Input Position"},
                new SelectListItem {Value="2",Text="Missing Number" },
                new SelectListItem { Value="3",Text="Climb Staircase" }
    };
    return View(lc);
}
```

and in my View

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.drop, new SelectList(Model.ProblemList,"Value","Text"), "-- Select Problem --") 
</div>
```

What I need to do is to pass the value from the list to another view. If that value is selected from the dropdown, you press a button and it should display a text in the second view. 
This is the button

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Solutions" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("button", "LeetCode")'"/>
</div>
```

And what the button uses to access the second view.

```
public ActionResult button(LeetCode model, string button)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: `ProblemList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - creating another identical one using `new SelectList(...)` in the view is pointless extra overhead. You need javascript to update your `href`. And what do you actually want to pass to the method - just the value of `drop`? What is the `button` parameter for. And this will be a lot easier if you just use a form with `FormMethod.Get`

Comment: an ajax post of the required data to the post method  of a controller when the button is clicked would be a better idea?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I need the button parameter later, when I will have two buttons and switch between them. This is not related to my problem. I think that if I pass the value, it would be easier to show that string to the 2nd view.

Comment: Just use 2 submit buttons (both with `name="button"` and different values and use a form with `FormMethod.Get` to make a GET to your method. It will pass the value of the clicked button and the value of the selected option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the selected value via query string with the current value selected and read it from query string in the second view.

Assuming id of drop down is "drpdwn" so this should work

```
<input type="button" value="Solutions" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("button", "LeetCode")?selectedvalue='+document.getElementById("drpdwn").value;"/>
```

**EDIT #1**

Create a JS function which accepts the base URL and redirect based on different conditions.

```
<input type="button" value="Solutions" onclick="redir('@Url.Action("button", "LeetCode")'"/> 

function redir(baseUrl){
    // some logic
    location.href=baseUrl+'?selectedvalue='+document.getElementById("drpdwn").value;
}
```

Comment: And how is that possible? With Linq?

Comment: @GeorgeGreat I have updated the answer with a sample code

Comment: And I can pass the value from drpdwn in my 2nd view? Can I do this with some condition?